# pip install from requirements work but unable to find the same libraries through ansible

Tags: python, pip, ansible

I have a few local packages that I install through Requirements.txt. This is a sample from Requirements.txt

```
-e apisdk
```

This works fine through

```
pip install -r Requirements.txt
```

The result is that pip runs

```
pip setup.py develop
```

for the apisdk package. This is the expected behavior

However when the same is called through ansible

```
tasks:
    - pip: virtualenv={{env_dir}}/testenv
           virtualenv_python=python2.7
           requirements={{app_dir}}/Requirements.txt
```

I receive following error

```
apisdk should either be a path to a local project or a VCS url beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+
```

Where am I going wrong. I am not running ansible from the app_dir directory but another place.

Comment: The `-e` argument requies a local project of source control system URL. Where are you trying to get `apisdk` from?

Comment: Klaus. Yes it's local. And as I said it works fine standalone but not through ansible

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer. The pip command also supports a chdir parameter. Change the directory to app_dir before running pip. This solved the issue.